# 'int' object is not subscriptable python error

Tags: python, string

My problem is error that you can see abowe. Here is my code. I want to check if n1 spelled backwards is equal to n2. Error is in line 6. I tried to user [::-1] but i think my knowledge about this is to small to use it well. Can you help?

```
import string
n1 = int(input("Your first number: "))
n2 = int(input("Your second number: "))
str(n1)
str(n2)
if n1 == n2[::-1]:
    print("numbers are mirrored")
else:
    print("numbers are not mirrored")
```

Comment: try not casting them to `int` on the input so that they can be reversed

Comment: on fourth line `str(n1)`, note the result is discarded, the same as `_ = str(n1)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `input(...)` function returns a `str` value, so if you wanted you could have code like:

```py
n1 = input("Your first number: ")
n2 = input("Your second number: ")

print(f'numbers are {"not " if n1 != n2[::-1] else ""}mirrored')
```

Out:

```
Your first number: 123
Your second number: 321
numbers are mirrored
```

Answer (score 0):

the whole problem is switching them from int to string, try getting rid of that code:

```
import string
n1 = input("Your first number: ")
n2 = input("Your second number: ")

if n1 == n2[::-1]:
    print("numbers are mirrored")
else:
    print("numbers are not mirrored")
```